# Collection preview image on Opensea not refreshing

Tags: metadata, opensea

How can I refresh collection preview image on Opensea?
I have found some solutions to refresh metadata on an item/token, but not on collection image.
Please help.

Answer (score 0):

I also stumbled upon this issue a couple times. It does not seem OpenSea has a solution for the whole collection refresh. They only have API to refresh individual tokens (that can be triggered manually on the token page on OpenSea).

But then I found this neat tool (not mine) that basically goes through each token and requests metadata refresh one-by-one programmatically https://www.nftrefreshmetadata.com. Just 1 click - and it worked like a charm for a 3k collection, although takes some time (there is a progress bar as well)